# Push only updated rails files from git using Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

How can I push or sync only new files in my app without redeploying the entire app. I used command "cap production deploy" for the initial upload is there any command for follow on uploads?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but this is a scary idea. Typically it's smart to keep around past deploys in case your current deploy fails. If you're just uploading changed files it's harder to get back to the last successful deploy.

Comment: Good idea @jaydel - but when I redeploy by uploading the entire app, it deletes all the user photos in the db

Comment: hm. do you have an initializer or some job that clears those? I wouldn't expect data in the db to change unless you've specifically set your deploy up to do that. I'm out of my depth here though. I've never tried to do what you're trying to do with cap

Comment: Make sure you are storing photos in a place like `public/system` or `public/uploads`, and then include that directory in Capistrano's `:linked_dirs`, as shown in the capistrano-rails README: https://github.com/capistrano/rails#symlinks . That way your photos will remain accessible on subsequent deploys.

Comment: @MattBrictson is correct, most probably the answer you are looking for here is using Capistrano's ```:linked_dirs```. All files inside the folders specified here are used in all releases of your deployment. A sample you can see here is the ```production.log``` file, which is not deleted every time you redeploy since you would want to see the previous logs.

Comment: Perfect! It works after adding public/uploads to the :linked_dirs. Many thanks to you all.